# Invoke-Sqlcmd ran SQL script capture verbose output

Tags: sql-server, powershell

I need to do health check on various servers on daily basis. I have SQL script which includes missing indexes, duplicate indexes, CPU and memory, recovery, failed job, last backup etc in one script.

I am running this script manually on sever and changing result to text (I have made script which use print statement so I can directly copy and paste result).

Now I want to run this script with PowerShell but I am not getting result to text format with `row-column` format.

**Code:**

```
$RESULT = (Invoke-Sqlcmd -InputFile $sqlscript -ServerInstance $server -Database $databse -Verbose 4>&1) |
          Out-File $outfile
```

I am getting all the print statement but not the result in text file.

Comment: So you're trying to redirect the verbose stream (`4`) to the success stream (`1`) and it's not working. Please clarify the specific symptom by directly updating your answer: Does the verbose output still shows in the console, or is it simply discarded? What PowerShell version? What version of the SQL Server PowerShell module?

Comment: PSVersion 5.0 & SQL Server 2012. yes, I am trying to redirect the verbose stream 4 to the success stream 1. Its working fine but not getting in table form. Its coming in e.g Row1 : value                                                                                  
                           Row2 : value                                                                              and I need output in table form for all the queries which has been used in my script. I have tried format-table all options but not getting output as in sql server query windows with result to text options.

Comment: Please add that information _directly to your question_, which also allows you can to properly format the incorrect output vs. expected output.

Answer (score 0):

A more appropriate way to do this is as follows.

```
[string]$SqlsSript = '..\path\'
[string]$ConnectionString = '...'

$DataSet = Invoke-SqlCmd -ConnectionString $Connectionstring -InputFile $SqlScript -As DataSet
```

You can then explore the $DataSet collection, i.e

```
$DataSet.Tables[0].Rows
```

Which you can then transform / output to a file if you like.

*Do ensure that your SqlScript returns a table, e.g. a table variable.*

Comment: sqlscript returns more than one table. I am getting output only in one table but not all

Comment: Hence the use of a DataSet as output; it contains multiple tables. $DataSet.Tables[0], $DataSet.Tables[1], etc.

Comment: Try  using -OutputAs DataSet, or -OutputAs DataTables

Also, take a look at Get-Help Invoke-SqlCmd -Examples

Comment: I did that but it is giving only for one table not other tables. I am using verbose here with 4&1.

Comment: My sql script contains print command as well as multiple tables like ... 1. cpu usage for server .... sql query 1   2. memory usage ..... sql query 2 etc ...

Comment: The PRINT output is likely not going to be returned by Invoke-SqlCmd by default, which I assume is why you're using the -verbose switch.  

From a design perspective you shouldn't develop these two parts [SQL, PS] in isolation; Your SQL query should return datatypes that PowerShell can handle as standard output.  The fact that you're redirecting verbose output to stdout is part of your problem, and explains why you're only getting the first table of data back.